# Como acomodar los meses en dygraph? En R

Tags: r

una pregunta estoy trabajando con dygraph en R y quiero graficar 12 meses de un resultado, sin embargo a pesar de que si sale el resultado cuando me pongo sobre el ultimo mes no me sale el nombre de ese mes que en el caso de la imagen es mayo 2019, ademas junio 2018 (el primer mes del grafico) me sale exactamente sobre el eje y. como puedo hacer para correrlos un poco como por ejemplo donde esta señalado en color verde?

Esto es importante por que la mayoria de la gente van a pensar que mayo no esta graficado cuando en realidad si lo esta.

Gracias por cualquier ayuda que me puedan dar.

El codigo que tengo para graficar es el siguiente

```
dygraph(datos,"titulo") %>%  
  dyAxis("y", label= "eje y", valueRange = c(0, 110)) %>%  
  dyAxis("x", label = "Mes y año", drawGrid = FALSE) %>% 
  dySeries(drawPoints = TRUE, pointShape = "square", color = "blue") %>%
  dyRangeSelector(dateWindow = ds[c(length(ds)-11,length(ds))]) %>% 
  dyLimit(95, "Mínimo permitido (95)", strokePattern = "solid", color = "red")
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Es un tema complejo, casi estoy tentado a decirte que no se puede. Los `ticks` de cualquiera de los ejes, no son valores que se puedan establecer de antemano, ya que se trata de un gráfico interactivo, es dygraph quién se encarga de establecerlos en todo momento. Ten en cuenta que se puede ajustar los límites con el selector en cualquier momento y los `ticks` se recalculan siempre. Lo único que se me ocurre, es que investigues por el lado de la función `dyAxis` puedes usar el  parámetro `ticker` y pasarle un código "ad-hoc" en Javascript que se encargue de dibujar los `ticks` que quieras.